# Error while installing Omnet++

Tags: 14.04, error-handling, configure

after I ran ./configure in Terminal I got this error:

```
configure: error: Cannot find osgEarth. At least the development version of libosgearth and the openscenegraph-plugin-osgearth package is required.
```

Before I started installing omnet, I had installed osgEarth via Synaptic package Manager. Does someone know how to solve this problem?

I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Did you install the **development version** of libosgearth? `libosgearth-dev - osgEarth development files`

Comment: Yes, also via Synaptic Package Manager.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was related to `liblzma.so.5` library. Here is how to fix it:

1. Locate `liblzma.so.5`

   ```
   $ find /lib -name "liblzma.so.5 
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5

   $ find /usr -name "liblzma.so.5" 
   /usr/local/lib/liblzma.so.5
   ```

   I discovered that I had 2 instances of the same library.
2. Remove the one in `/usr/local/lib` and any symbolic link

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/local/lib/liblzma.so
   sudo rm /usr/local/lib/liblzma.so.5
   sudo rm /usr/local/lib/liblzma.so.5.0.3
   ```
3. ```
   sudo ldconfig
   ```

Now `./configure` did not complain about osgEarth while installing Omnet++